# In my Ubuntu 16.04, the low version zim will damage my maintained notebook folder?

Tags: 16.04

I have been using zim for long time, but I also keep to use the relative new version of Ubuntu (in Ubuntu 20.04, zim is 0.72 version). I also use git to maintain my zim notbook foler, but sometimes I must use lower version of Ubuntu in my work environment, such as Ubuntu 16.04, I have realized the zim app in these Ubuntu does have different version, so far what I am worrying about is if the zim verion 0.65 will damage my maintained notebootk folder or not,  I need to know the risk I am having.

Thanks indeed!

Comment: You're using `git`, what are you worrying about?

Comment: Why did you tag 14.04?

Comment: @pLumo, thanks I can roll back to fix it.    I aso use wordpress, I never worry this kind of issue, because the articles are save database.

Comment: @Plumo I cannot find 16.04 tag when I was submitting the post,  I have fixed it to 16.04

Answer (score 1):

Zim works based on a hierarchical structure of your notes in plain text files with some markup. At first run, it indexes these text files and stores the index in a sqlite3 database in a hidden .zim directory in the top-level folder of the notebook.

This design ensures that your actual data and folder structure will not be damaged trying to open it with a previous version. At most, you may need to reindex the data: use "Tools - Update index".